# A query on absolute positioned element in CSS

Tags: html, css

Please check the [JSFIDDLE code here](https://jsfiddle.net/DARKHELL/nq54hduv/1/).

I have an `absolute` positioned child and a `relative` positioned parent. I expect to see the entire `absolute` positioned child at all circumstances. When I place the `overflow : auto` for the grandparent, it's hiding the `absolute` positioned element within the scroll.

What I am seeing is this (Absolute child hidden in scroll):

[image]

What I want to see is (Able to see the entire absolute child with `overflow: auto` set on the grand parent):

[image]

```css
.GrandParent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 500;
}

.Child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="GrandParent">
    <div class="Parent">
      <div class="Child">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the question here what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: So you want the scrollbars and the overflow? Are you expecting for the child to still be scrollable and it's overflowed areas move as the container is scrolled?

Comment: @JHeth, Yes I want the scroll bars too and I would like the absolute element item to be seen outside.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, I want to have overflow set to the grandparent and still be able to see the entire absolute child. I was working on a modal and it's hiding the dropdown panel of a dropdown. I need to set the overflow auto to the modal, but when I open the dropdown, it should be seen outside the modal.

Comment: @METALHEAD in light of your explanation to AlwaysHelping about your actual situation the only real solution is to use Javascript. You can't have your overflow and scroll it too.

An old trick when there's a dropdown that would be clipped off is to remove and append a copy of the dropdown to the body or any other container above the grandparent on click and absolutely position it to match the offsetTop and left of the original dropdown... it's a lot of work for little reward or you could adjust your layout, maybe the dropdown should be a button group.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `.Child` is relative to the `.Parent` not the `.GrandParent`. The `.Parent`'s content is being hidden via `overflow: auto` on it's container element which is the `.GrandParent`. One way of solving this issue is to have another container that the `.Child` is relative to. In my code example below, `.Child` will no longer be relative to parent so the positioning can get tricky. This is one of the reasons why libraries such as [popperjs](https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core) was created. You will need JavaScript to reposition the `.Child` on-scroll.

```css
.MainContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.GrandParent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: auto;
}

.Parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 500;
}

.Child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 50px);
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.some-modal-content {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="MainContainer">
    <div class="GrandParent">
      <div class="Parent">
        <div class="Child">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="some-modal-content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Not my down-vote BUT That's not what the OP wants to achieve. Are you sure on your answer.

Comment: when question seems to be impossible suggestion, explanation and sometimes trick are required and this should be good answer for the question

Answer (score 1):

1. `Child` is out of the document flow(new block formatting context), just offset relative to `Parent`；
2. `Child` box inside `Parent` (relative), but overflowed, set `Parent` overflow property to control layout visibility;
3. `Child` + `Parent` box inside `GrandParent`, overflowed, set `GrandParent` overflow property to control layout visibility;

They have a ‘wrapped’ relationship, The content outside the area is controlled by the outer overflow property。

Except for `fixed` attribute positioning, other positioning is controlled by the wrapping layer, automatically height content, or scrolling, or being cropped and hidden.

- [position - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [overflow - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

---

Through the wrap layer we generally control the display of the inner layer in this way.

`active` may be come from a click event, or hover event, etc.

```
<div class="GrandParent active">
  <div class="Parent">
    <div class="Child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.Child { display:none; ... }
.GrandParent.active .Child { display:block; }
```